# Get latest entry in MySQL if it meets criteria

Tags: mysql

I'm finishing up a system for buying event tickets, and I need to be able to check if there are still tickets available.

I have a table (tbl_rel_order_status) that makes a relation between orders and new statuses received from a payment gateway (like, say, PayPal). Every new transaction generates a new entry.

Structure and example for **tbl_rel_order_status** (tbl_order_id and tbl_status_order_id are FKs)

```
| id | tbl_order_id | tbl_status_order_id | datetime            |
| 1  | 1            |         1           | 2016-08-01 18:20:00 |
| 2  | 1            |         3           | 2016-08-01 18:20:00 |
```

Structure and example for **tbl_order** (tbl_ticket_id, tbl_client_id and tbl_payment_method_id are FKs)

```
| id | tbl_ticket_id | tbl_client_id | tbl_payment_method_id | qnty |
| 1  | 1             |         1     | 1                     |  40  |
| 2  | 1             |         2     | 1                     |  3   |
```

I have a few "cancellation statuses" (namely: 6,7,8,11,13,15), which all mean that for some reason that amount of tickets can be made available again for other clients.

**Here's the thing:** I'm working on a query to retrieve the quantities of tickets which have as **latest** status any of the mentioned above. If not, the query should skip to the next ticket (that's where I'm stuck).

```
SELECT tbl_order.qnty
FROM (SELECT tbl_order_id,tbl_status_order_id
      FROM tbl_rel_order_status
      WHERE tbl_status_order_id IN ('6','7','8','11','13','15')
      ORDER BY id DESC) inside
INNER JOIN tbl_order on tbl_order.id = inside.tbl_order_id
GROUP BY tbl_status_order_id
```

With that query I can only get the ones that DO have any of these, but not for the latest (or newest) DB entry.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b21c/1/0)

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the latest status using a query like this:

```
select o.*,
       (select ros.tbl_status_order_id
        from tbl_rel_order_status ros
        where ros.tbl_order_id = o.id
        order by ros.datetime desc
        limit 1
       ) as last_status
from tbl_order o;
```

From this, I think you want:

```
select o.*,
       (select ros.tbl_status_order_id
        from tbl_rel_order_status ros
        where ros.tbl_order_id = o.id
        order by ros.datetime desc
        limit 1
       ) as last_status
from tbl_order o
having last_status in ('6', '7', '8', '11', '13', '15');
```

Comment: Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row  - I've just edited the question with a fiddle, in case you want to play with it.

Comment: @LeandroDimitrio . . . Try the version now with `limit 1`.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you, sir :)